# Laravel multiple whereHas criteria for relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have two tables - contacts and visits:

Contacts Table

```
id    | name          
----- | -------
1     | Joe
2     | Sally
```

Visits Table

```
id    | contact_id | pathname  | referrer                
----- | -------    | -------   | -------
1     | 1          | about     | google
2     | 1          | pricing   | null
3     | 1          | signup    | null
4     | 2          | about     | null
5     | 2          | signup    | null
```

Using eloquent, I would like to retrieve all **contacts** that have a both a **pathname** = 'signup' AND a **referrer** = 'google'.

What I've got so far is:

```
Contact::whereHas('visits', function($query) {
    $query->where('pathname','=','signup');
})
->orWhereHas('visits', function($query) {
    $query->where('referrer','=','google');
})
->get();
```

Which properly retrieves all contacts that have visited either the pricing OR signup page.

However, this example would also retrieve **Sally** (from the example table above), since she visited signup, but was not referred by google. I need a way to only retrieve **Joe**, who was both referred by google and visited pricing.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use:

```
Contact::whereHas('visits', function($query) {
    $query->where('pathname','=','signup');
})
->whereHas('visits', function($query) {
    $query->where('referrer','=','google');
})
->get();
```

Comment: This creates multiple exists. Rather do where or inside closure

Answer (score 19):

A refined version of the code above:

```
Contact::whereHas('visits', function($query) {
    $query->where('pathname','signup')->where('referrer','google');
})->get();
```

Several noteworthy points:

1. You can chain `where()` clauses within a closure.
2. The default operator for a where clause is `=`, so you can omit it.
3. Use multiple `whereHas()` clauses, when accessing multiple related models.

Comment: why I cannot use if condition or when condition within whereHas scope ? I want to skip where('referrer' , $params->ref) if $parm->ref is null or empty. Please show me how can I do that .

Comment: @ThatoeAung You can use the whereNotNull method instead if you to skip null values

Comment: Better than the above version as above version creates a multiple exists and this one a single exists

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using `orWherehas` for the second query.
Use `whereHas` for both queries and everything will be fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).